# Button to activate Javascript code in my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, xcode, button

How would I be able to incorporate a button into my HTML code so that when the user clicks the button, it starts running a javascript?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried..? did you atleast try a [google](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+execute+a+javascript+button+on+click+of+a+button&oq=how+to+execute+a+javascript+button+on+click+of+a+button&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.12550j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8) search..?

Answer (score -1):

You really should do some more research before asking such a basic question, but for completion sake:

```
<button onclick="alert('hello world');">Hello</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

There are many approaches. Here's one.

```
<button id="my-button">
```

Then

```
document.getElementById("my-button").addEventListener("click", function(event)
{
    // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's really not cool to just throw code at someone without explaining it, especially when the OP has made no attempt to understand the problem.